# HTML Encoded Data-Binding Expressions

Tags: asp.net

i am using a repeater to bind data in a table i am follwing a tutorial from a book, i want to bring in workshopid from the orderlines table i have tried to pull it in but i keep getting this error

'Technology.Models.Order' does not contain a definition for 'Orderlines' and no extension method 'Orderlines' accepting a first argument of type 'Technology.Models.Order' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetOrders"
 ItemType="Technology.Models.Order">
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
 <td><%#: Item.Name %></td>
 <td><%#: Item.City %></td>
 **<td>  <%#: Item.Orderlines.Workshop_WorkshopID %></td>**

<td><%# Item.OrderLines.Sum(ol => ol.Quantity) %></td>
 <td><%# Total(Item.OrderLines).ToString("C") %> </td>
 <td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The object that you are listing can be empty or can not have a proper mapping. If you are using EF, the query you need to include the name of the other table using the Include code ("Name tabel")
Hope help you